# Azure AD authentication with JWT token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, bearer-token

I am using ASP .NET core web API (3.1). Where I need to authorized the user in 2 ways. First by SQL identity (with user name and password) and second by Azure AD SSO single tenant (by clicking Microsoft login button). I used JWT for SQL authentication and send back a JWT bearer token. This part is working fine. I need a way to do same JWT bearer token sending feature with Azure AD in same application. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

The guidance provided here should help you in answering the query.